# How to get axis's coordinates when i click on column in Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have timeline chart. Columns show some periods of time like 'Idle', 'Active' and etc. I want to get Y Axis value(time) of place where I clicked

[image: [That's my chart][1].]

I tried `click` event for chart, but it wasn't fired if I clicked on column, but it returns `yAxis` value

```
 series: {
   events: {
     click: function (event) {
   },
 },
```

Events for series or points returned only `column(event.toElement.Point)`

Comment: Hi, i don't suppose you are able to create a basic Plunkr example? This would help us greatly in finding a solution for you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fLcobofm/
I just want to get the coordinates of the points on the axes when I click on the column. Chart's click event doesn't work when i cliked on column, but i need its yAxis property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the click event's x/y coordinates and convert them to yAxis values.

```
plotOptions: {
    columnrange: {
      events: {
        click: function(event) {
          alert(this.yAxis.toValue(event.x, false));

        },
      }
    }
  },
```

Note that because you are using `chart.inverted = true`, you'll need to use the `x` value to get the point on the `yAxis`.

http://jsfiddle.net/fLcobofm/13/

Comment: I am very grateful for your help, Barbara. That's what i want